# how to switch to windows security window and insert credentials

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

Here are my steps
1.Using selenium webdriver I am opening Edge

2.Then after click a link it opens popup security window. I am attaching a screenshot

[image]
3. I tried to switch that window using many different ways. It is not an alert because when I called for alert it says no such alerts are open.

I tried to call following but it gives error

```
 window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
```

Following two lines gave me 1 handles:

```
handles = driver.window_handles
print("Number of handles ", len(handles))

Output: 
Number of handles  1
```

if it is not alert, not a window, what is it?  view source code does not print anything.

All i need is insert user name and password and then click "OK" button

4. I put the program for sleep 20 seconds and then manually selected the cursor to user name text box. The executed following code but it does nothing

   ActionChains(driver).send_keys("Test").perform()

Side Note: Need answer for only for Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium only works for browser automation. The Windows Security pop-up is an OS-level dialog and Selenium will not be able to recognize it. You could use third party tools like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) with Selenium to automate non-browser based functionality. For the detailed steps, you could refer to [this article](https://testguild.com/selenium-how-to-handle-windows-based-dialogs-and-pop-ups/).

Comment: how a browser based app pop-up os level security login? This is just a java based app

Comment: Of course a browser based app can trigger os level pop-up. Like a print pop-up or a browsing window when uploading a file. We operate them in a browser app but the browser can call the system components. The Windows Security pop-up is the same, it is triggered by the browser but shown by the operating system, so we can't automate it directly with selenium webdriver.